# cakephp / don't store all user data in session while using authComponent

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, components

I'm new to cakephp, and building my first project with the brand new 2.1.

I use auth and session components to build a simple login system. Everything works alright. I'm using a form auth, with custom requested field to use email as login.

When I try

```
var_dump($this->Session->read('Auth.User'));
```

I can see all my User data stored in the session, but I don't need all of them here. Of course I can rewrite the session with only the subset of data I need, my session are stored on memecache, and I can't waste memory.

I want to be able to update cakephp easily, so I prefer to not rewrite parts of cakephp components.

I'm looking for a solution letting me specify which fields I need in the session.

Answer (score 4):

You may write your own auth component like this:

```
class MyAuthComponent extends AuthComponent {

var $storeFields = array();

protected function cleanupUserData($user) {
    if (empty($this->storeFields)) return $user;

    retrun array_intersect_key($user, array_flip($this->storeFields));
}

    public function login($user = null) {
        $this->_setDefaults();

        if (empty($user)) {
            $user = $this->identify($this->request, $this->response);
        }
        if ($user) {
            $this->Session->renew();
        $user = $this->cleanupUserData($user);
        $this->Session->write(self::$sessionKey, $user);
        }
        return $this->loggedIn();
    }
}
```

and then write something like this in controller:

```
$this->MyAuth->storeFields = array('email', 'name', 'dob');
```